# How to change Textfield value Each time window show

Tags: extjs

I am using ExtJs for my Application. I made a window in which i have some fields . one field is name which is changing each time when window show.
but since i am not destroying window on button click it not rendering again and showing previous data only. How I make sure for new data.

My code

Code of My Field in form reside in window

```
 items: [
    {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        name: 'Assigned To',
        queryMode: 'local',
        store: this.getResourceStore(),
        displayField: 'svmx_name',
        labelAlign: 'top',
        fieldLabel: 'Assigned_To',
        listeners: {
            scope: this,
            select: function (combo, record, index) {
                var form = display_form.getForm();
                var id = record.getId();
                form.findField('ResourceId').setValue(id);
            },
            afterrender: function (combo, record, index) {
                console.log(this.getResourceName());
                combo.setValue(this.getResourceName());
            },
        }
    },
```

Setting fields in window.

```
if (!this.win) {
    this.win = Ext.widget({
        xtype: 'editorwindow',
        resourceStore: Ext.getCmp('scheduler1').getResourceStore(),
        eventStore: Ext.getCmp('scheduler1').getEventStore(),
        wrapper: Ext.getCmp('scheduler1').getWrapper(),
        resourceName: targetResource,
        startdate: date,
        targetData: dragSource.data,
    });
}
this.win.show();
```

Comment: Did you try to take care of this in the window's _show_ event listener?

Comment: How i can do that @scebotari any Idea? 
Currently i am checking condition if already window is there i am destroying it and making new one . but looking for new ideas

Answer (score 0):

I would define an own window class with a [config object](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-config) to set your required data.
The framework will create setter and getter functions for you.

```
Ext.define(MyFieldsWindow, {
    extend: Ext.window.Window,
    xtype: 'myfieldswindow',
    config: {
        resourceName: '',
        startdate: null,
        targetData: null
    },
}
```

In the update function set the value to the specific component.
The `updateResourceName` function will look like.

```
updateResourceName: function (newResourceName, oldResourceName) {
    var resourceNameCmp = this.getComponent('resourceName');
    resourceNameCmp.setValue(newResourceName);
},
```

Now you can set the config when you create an instance.

```
if (!this.win) {
    this.win = Ext.create({
        xtype: 'myfieldswindow',
        resourceStore: Ext.getCmp('scheduler1').getResourceStore(),
        eventStore: Ext.getCmp('scheduler1').getEventStore(),
        wrapper: Ext.getCmp('scheduler1').getWrapper(),
        resourceName: targetResource,
        startdate: date,
        targetData: dragSource.data,
    });
}
this.win.show();
```

Or you can set it at runtime with the setter method.

```
this.win.setResourceName('Roli Agrawal');
```

The window class looks like.

```
Ext.define(MyFieldsWindow, {
    extend: Ext.window.Window,

    config: {
        resourceName: '',
        startdate: null,
        targetData: null
    },

    updateResourceName: function (newResourceName, oldResourceName) {
        var resourceNameCmp = this.getComponent('resourceName');
        resourceNameCmp.setValue(newResourceName);
    },

    updateStartDate: function () {/*similar code like above*/ },
    updateTargetDate: function () {/*similar code like above*/ },

    items: [
        {
            itemId: 'resourceName',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        },
        /* additional items*/
    ]
});
```